# Change point size in Basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

How can I reduce the point size of a place I have plotted on the map with its coordinates using Basemap in Python?

[image: existing plot]

The code for the plotting is:

```
m = Basemap(width=4000000,height=4000000,projection='lcc',
        resolution='c',lat_1=45.,lat_2=55,lat_0=20,lon_0=80.)
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='aqua')
m.drawcountries()
m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.50)
m.fillcontinents(color='green', alpha = 0.6, lake_color='aqua')
for i in range(len(lngtd)):
    lon = lngtd[i]
    lat = lattd[i]
    xpt,ypt = m(lon,lat)
    lonpt, latpt = m(xpt,ypt,inverse=True)
    m.plot(xpt,ypt,'ro')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Use `markersize` option, see document here  https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding full answer to future visitors. Add the markersize keyword to the line:

```
m.plot(xpt,ypt,'ro')
```

to make:

```
m.plot(xpt,ypt,'ro', ms="2.0")
```

Docs: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html